# Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties()

Tags: angular

I'm working on upgrading my application from Angular 10 to Angular 13 and I'm getting the following error

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The npm script 'start -- --configuration=dev-dmz' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Option '--' has been specified multiple times. The value '56056' will be used.

Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:

Data path "" must NOT have additional properties().

)
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The npm script 'start -- --configuration=dev-dmz' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Option '--' has been specified multiple times. The value '56056' will be used.

Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:

Data path "" must NOT have additional properties().

---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String scriptName, String pkgManagerCommand, Int32 portNumber, ILogger logger, DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String scriptName, String pkgManagerCommand, Int32 portNumber, ILogger logger, DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at PPF.Core.Middleware.RequestTracingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Here's my package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "ppf.maintenance.web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "14.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^14.0.2",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^14.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^11.2.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.2",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-currency": "2.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^10.0.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "service": "^0.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^14.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Here's my angular.json file

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "PPF.Maintenance.Web": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": true,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/static",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "oidc-client.min.js",
                "input": "node_modules/oidc-client/dist",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/pdfjs",
                "output": "/assets/pdfjs"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "production-dmz": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod-dmz.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "dev-dmz": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev-dmz.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PPF.Maintenance.Web:build",
            "publicHost": "http://maintenance.portalapps.com",
            "disableHostCheck": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "PPF.Maintenance.Web:build:production"
            },
            "production-dmz": {
              "browserTarget": "PPF.Maintenance.Web:build:production-dmz"
            },
            "dev-dmz": {
              "browserTarget": "PPF.Maintenance.Web:build:dev-dmz"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PPF.Maintenance.Web:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "PPF.Maintenance.Web-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "PPF.Maintenance.Web:serve"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "PPF.Maintenance.Web"
}
```

Any ideas on what it going on?  I'm assuming this has to do with some dependency issues